# Locked room poison mystery!

Tags: story, mystery

Aaron and his sister Bethany call the police when their live in Grandmother, Candice, failed to get up for breakfast. She was old and ill, and they feared the worst-- especially then they were unable to get into her room! The police break down the door, shattering it in two. Candice is dead, poisoned! The police find

- 8 locks on the door installed by Candice, all of which appeared to be bolted
- a glass of water by the bedside table, half full
- a bottle of heart failure medicine (slow release capsule form)
- *The ABC Murders* by Agatha Christie, cover torn violently. It now reads "The BC by Agatha hristie"

Forensics find the following:

- Candice died from the poison sometime in the night, around 1 AM.
- No poison in the water.
- No poison in the remaining pills.
- No needle marks.
- No poison on the book, and she wasn't licking it anyway :P
- The poison would've acted quickly, once the lethal dose was absorbed by her system, she would have died in 15 minutes.
- Pathologists do not suspect suicide. In her condition, if she wanted death, all she had to do was stop taking the pills and go to sleep. She'd never wake.

According to interviews:

- Aaron and Bethany confirm that Candice shut herself in at 8 pm. They remained in each other's sight until they turned in at 10.
- Aaron stands to inherit a large fortune. Bethany stands to inherit a small amount by comparison
- Aaron and Candice were getting into arguments, and she began to distrust him. Candice wanted Bethany to pick up her prescriptions, but she was too busy, so Aaron was forced to do it.
- According to her Doctor, Candice knew her life depended on the pills. She did ask that, should life become unbearable, if she would be able to go quietly if she stopped her pills. He said yes.

But! When the will was read... Aaron actually inherited nothing! Candice changed her will last week! Bethany still got her share, but the bulk went to a long estranged nephew living in Ireland! Irish authorities confirm that he has been in Ireland for the past 6 months.

Who murdered Candice, and how?

Hint

> There is only one murderer, and Candice figured it out as she was dying. Did she find a way to tell us?

Hint 2

> You will not need anything outside the lists to solve the puzzle. I play fair. No one turns out to be a fish or have a high powered sniper poison dispensing rifle :P

Hint 3 -- A big hint

> The will change is a clue as to HOW the murder was committed, not who. Agatha Christie is a very intentional reference. The *Columbo* episode *Try and Catch Me* also may help you solve this case. If you're familiar with the plot, then you should know what Edmund did. Everything he did.

### Edit! I added letters back into the title of the book. Initially I was going to use a different book, so I took out too many letters.

Comment: A clear improvement over your other mysteries (+1). It's good that you've added enough information so that everything is contained within the world of this puzzle

Comment: As a note here - actual *hints* (information not *necessary* to solve the puzzle) should probably not be posted immediately but only after some time has passed with no forward progress being made. Information that *is necessary* to solve the puzzle shouldn’t be labeled or spoilered as a hint because it’s not.

Comment: Are these important? rot13("NP Zheqref NP") If so I think I have the who, not how.

Comment: Also rot13(vf gur tynff shyy, unys shyy be rzcgl?)

Comment: @Abbas yes it is important! And I'll edit to address your question.

Comment: Who's Edmund???

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath I think Edmund is a character in that episode of Columbo.

Comment: You should keep creating these puzzles! They're truly amazing and I enjoy them very much...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Muderer :**

> Aaron. The taken out alphabets from the title are A(Aaron) Muders C(Candice).

**How**

> Not completely sure about this, since the story states Aaron was *forced* to get the medicine, implying he didn't have a plan ready. Anyways I think adding poison in the tablets is really stupid since there was no way for Aaron to **know** which tablet she'd take first, when <s>and</s> the rest are all OK. It is also possible he didn't care when exactly Candice dies, in which case poisoning one tablet would be the way to go.

Another way could be

> He could tamper with the medicine bottle, add a poisonous gas to the bottle somehow so the pills would remain non lethal, but still killing through the bottle leaving no trace of the poison.

While thinking about something else entirely

> I think I found another way Aaron could've murdered Candice, provided there's a gap in the door. Aaron could've sealed the door, with plastic, inserted a pipe through the gap and pumped in gas. Bethany would've been in her room and wouldn't find out, there'd be no evidence of the gas, as it would've released slowly throughout the night.

Comment: You got it! That's how Candice was able to disinherit her murderer. He laced one of the pills was poison *before* she changed her will. She changed it, but by then it was too late, it was only a matter of time before the fatal dose.

Comment: You sniped me! Nooo! To be honest, though, I think my answer is more definite on the how (the way the murderer did it)... @GridAlien, what do you think?

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath I don't think I did. I was the one who asked for the importance of the missing letters and *not* the remaining ones. You then updated you answer to the actual killer while I was writing my answer.

Comment: @Abbas - Where did you ask for importance? EDIT: Ohh! I just saw that...

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath, I like that Abbas's answer touches on Aaron being unable to know exactly when the poison is consumed, despite the slight vaguer-y on how many [items] were poisoned ("And the rest were all OK" implies 1). Both answers are satisfactory to me, and you both did a great job!

Comment: @GridAlien actually I did say `in which case poisoning one tablet would be the way to go`. I have corrected the line you refer to, Having ADD and not being a native Englsh speaker causes me to write or talk gibberish sometimes. :-) I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @Abigail I thought of all these points. The answers I guess are: Candice was having arguments with Aaron not Bethany whom she was on good terms with. she would therefore assume Aaron was trying to murder her because that is the simple human psychology, you are always looking to validate your own beliefs, I think it is called confirmation bias.

Comment: Candice was alone in her room for approximately 4 hours and 40-45 minutes, she had (probably) just thought about going to bed, after a little googling I found that heart medicine is usually taken just before going to bed. In that time she had only drank the water and taken her tablet. Again there's some psychology involved. She would have  attributed the fault to the pills rather than water because it was brought by Aaron and simply because among pill and water, pill seems the better object for poison (Remember she wouldn't have long to think things over).

Comment: As for opening the door, I doubt she'd have had the time/strength in the end. Though she should've shouted and called for help. I don't know why she didn't, perhaps the nature of the poison refrained her.

Comment: @Abigail True, but that part can be used as a way to wrap up the puzzle. Also I always like to say: "It is possible to arrive at the correct solution through incorrect reasoning and arrive at an incorrect solution through correct reasoning."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97509/discussion-between-abbas-and-abigail).

Answer (score 9):

I think it may have been

> The Doctor

Reasoning

> The letters which Candice tore from the book cover are **"A murders C"** which, when anagrammed, spell out **"Curer's Mad"** (she didn't have the letters to spell out Doctor).

How

> The doctor had given her an extra pill to take which was laced with poison and told her to take it with a glass of water if she was having trouble sleeping. Being a medical professional, he was able to do it in the correct way so that the poison would take effect only when ingested by Candice. From the last bullet point, Candice seems to put a lot of faith in her doctor so would have no problem accepting his advice.

Sidenote

> The normally moral doctor was bribed by a mysterious Irish gentleman standing to come into a significant sum of money.

Answer (score 6):

It was

> Aaron

because

> what was ripped out from the book was *A murders C*. *A*aron *murders* *C*andice?

A possible *why*:

> Aaron thought the he was still receiving the bulk of the will, so he thought that killing her would streamline his wealth. But he didn't know she had changed it so he wouldn't get anything!

A possible *how*:

> Aaron was picking up Candice's pills. It's possible that he slipped *one* poison pill in there and Candice happened to take it that night...

Comment: Your thinking is pretty solid, but it's not an envelope. Let me put it this way, with all of the items listed (including the poison in the body), you should be able to commit the murder yourself. You're on the right track thinking the book is the clue!

Comment: rot13(Gur jvyy jnf erqbar n jrrx rneyvre gur cngubybtvfgf guvax gur cbvfba jbhyq xvyy ure va 10-15 zvahgrf.)

Comment: @Abbas - Oh, right. I forgot about that!

Comment: @GridAlien - I changed my murderer and added a why to it. Did I get closer?

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath, you bet you're closer! Your why and how are still off, but you'll get there!

Comment: @GridAlien - Am I there? I just made another edit to my answer...

Comment: Yup, you're there now, just beat out by Abbas. Good job though!

Answer (score 5):

Just some guessing: 
Who:

> Aaron did it (Voldemort's Wrath saw this also) because Candice torn the book so that "A murders C" is torn away.

How:

> Aaron had to pick up the prescription for Candice, because Bethany was busy. He replaced the amount of pills that Candice normally takes with poison. Because these are slow release capsules it took a while before she had a lethal dose in her body. This is why she died around 1 pm.

Why:

> Candice and Aaron where arguing lately, and Aaron was afraid that she would change her will. To make sure that he would inherit his share, he killed her before she would change her mind. But he was too late